# Put object in array with Jackson mixin

Tags: java, code-generation, json-deserialization, mixins, objectmapper

I have some json and need to map it to other third party objects. JSON:

```
{
"date": "2023-01-01",
"employee": {
  "idNumber": "29255",
  "gender": "M",
  "age": 32
},
"product": {
  "productNo": 11,
  "productName": "someProduct"
},
  "building": {
    "buildingNo": 11,
    "buildingName": "someBuilding"
  }
}
```

The result object is like:

```
class Employee {
        String id;
        String gender;
        Integer age;
        Product[] products;
    }
    
    class Product {
        Integer id;
        String name;
    }
```

So I need to put product object in the Json to array of products. And as seen from Json it will always be a single product for such a structure. But maybe I'll want to add some other objects like building to the products. I wrote some mixin for this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EmployeeMixin {
    @JsonProperty("idNumber")
    Integer id;
    String gender;
    Integer age;
    @JsonProperty("product")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ProductArrayDeserializer.class)
    Product[] products;
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ProductMixin {
    @JsonProperty("productNo")
    Integer id;
    @JsonProperty("productName")
    String name;
}

public class ProductArrayDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Product[]> {
    @Override
    public Product[] deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        var jsonNode = p.readValueAsTree();
        Product product = ctxt.readValue(jsonNode.traverse(), Product.class);
        return new Product[]{product};
    }
}
```

But when I tying to parse it with object mapper I get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected end-of-input when trying read value of type `com.my.users.examples.mixin.Product`
 at [Source: (String)"{
    "date": "2023-01-01",
.....
}"; line: 11, column: 5] (through reference chain: com.my.users.examples.mixin.Employee["product"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1741)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1515)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1462)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:223)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:186)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.readValue(DeserializationContext.java:966)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.readValue(DeserializationContext.java:953)
at com.my.users.examples.mixin.ProductArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ProductArrayDeserializer.java:14)
at com.my.users.examples.mixin.ProductArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ProductArrayDeserializer.java:10)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:313)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:176)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4675)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3630)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3598)
at com.my.users.examples.mixin.MixinTest.main(MixinTest.java:12)
```

in line `Product product = ctxt.readValue(jsonNode.traverse(), Product.class);` of `ProductArrayDeserializer` class. Code for testing is next:

```
var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixIn(Employee.class, EmployeeMixin.class)
                .addMixIn(Product.class, ProductMixin.class);

        Employee employee = mapper.readValue(employeeJson);
```

What is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.